# Indefinite integral involving Spherical Bessel function of second kind

Tags: indefinite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Notation: $\mathrm{y}_l(x)$ is the [spherical Bessel function of *second* kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

I need to calculate the following indefinite integral: 
$$\int x^2\left(\mathrm{y}_l\left(x\right)\right)^2dx$$

I tried it using the differential equation itself and got no result. I have looked up the standard book of tables and [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) to no avail. I'm looking for any suggestions to obtain a closed-form expression. Thanks in advance!

Comment: CAS says: $\int x^2 y_l(x){}^2 \, dx=\frac{1}{4} \pi  x^2 Y_{\frac{1}{2}+l}(x){}^2-\frac{1}{4} \pi  x^2 Y_{-\frac{1}{2}+l}(x) Y_{\frac{3}{2}+l}+C$ where:$Y_l(x)$ is  Bessel function of the second kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same approach works as I gave in [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2825148/221811), except that this time the Wronskian terms vanish, so you obtain
$$ \int x^2 (y_l(x))^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}{4}(y_l''(x)y_l(x)-y_l'(x)y_l(x))+C, $$
which again can be simplified if desired.